# Extract and add string to each item on the webpage python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am **scraping** a website and I was able to extract relevant information from that. There are multiple pages in the site and I want to see from which forum I am extracting data i.e., I want `h1` to be added to each item in the page. How can I do it

```
urls = ['https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2019-adding-adaptive-cruise-454662/','https://www.f150forum.com/f118/adaptive-cruise-control-sensor-blockage-446041/']

for url in urls:
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for item in range(1,2):
            response = req.get(f"{url}index{item}/")
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
            posts = soup.find(id = "posts")
            link.append(url)
            for item in soup.findAll('h1',attrs={"class":"threadtitle"}):
                result = [item.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")]
                h1.append(result)
            for item in soup.findAll('a',attrs={"class":"bigusername"}):
                name = [item.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")]
                username.append(name)
                for i in username:
                    x = h1.join(username)
```

I want my result as

```
       h1                              username
2019 Adding Adaptive Cruise             KR2019
2019 Adding Adaptive Cruise             KR2019
2019 Adding Adaptive Cruise             bud2019lariat
Adaptive Cruise Control sensor Blockage danbart
Adaptive Cruise Control sensor Blockage Iggy F-150
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

urls = ['https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2019-adding-adaptive-cruise-454662/','https://www.f150forum.com/f118/adaptive-cruise-control-sensor-blockage-446041/']

lst = []
cols = ['h1', 'username']
for x in urls:
  req=requests.get(x)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content,'html.parser')
  threadtitle = soup.find('h1',attrs={"class":"threadtitle"})
  for item in soup.findAll('a',attrs={"class":"bigusername"}):
    lst.append([threadtitle.text,item.text])
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=cols)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some way to tie the thread title to the username. If there is only one thread title per page, you could just get the first title from the list or nest your username loop. You could print them out then if that is all you want or you could connect them with a tuple or class

```
urls = ['https://www.f150forum.com/f118/2019-adding-adaptive-cruise-454662/',
        'https://www.f150forum.com/f118/adaptive-cruise-control-sensor-blockage-446041/']

results = []
for url in urls:
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for index in range(1, 2):
            response = req.get(f"{url}index{index}/")
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
            posts = soup.find(id="posts")
            for title_element in soup.findAll('h1', attrs={"class": "threadtitle"}):
                title = title_element.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
                for name_element in soup.findAll('a', attrs={"class": "bigusername"}):
                    name = name_element.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
                    print(f'{title}\t\t{name}')

                    # or store for later
                    results.append((title, name))

# using later
for title, name in results:
    print(f'{title}\t\t{name}')
```

Comment: +1! And for good measure, even though it was in the original question, you can delete the `posts` variable since it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was using posts for extracting other features.